# Determine Connection Speed of TCP stream using SharpPcap

Tags: c#, tcp, sharppcap

I am working on a project and i am trying to find a way to determine the connection speed of a tcp stream in C# using sharppcap. Are there any methods i should look into? I have already coded a packet sniffer that collects tcp packets and seperates them by port number. I eventually want to determine the speed of the traffic coming over each port then display that information.

Comment: have you looked at statistics in the capture device? coupled with a simple timer, you should be able to calculate one.

Comment: If you have the packets, you know their size, and you know the time... ???

Comment: my problem is knowing when the connection has been set up so i can start the timer. should i just begin the timer when the first tcp packet comes over the port or is there a way to know exactly when the connection is established so i can start the timer then.

Comment: The connection starts when the TCP packet has the TCP flag `SYN`. The connection ends when the TCP packet has the TCP flags `FIN` or `RST`